# Why doesn't UIWebView reflow text after column width and gap are set via javascript?

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am loading an html file into a UIWebView and setting the "-webkit-column-width" and "-webkit-column-gap" style property via javascript in webViewDidFinishLoad, but the text isn't reflowing into columns.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    NSURL *urlForView = [self.book.chapterURLs objectAtIndex:0];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    self.webView.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlForView]];
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{   
    NSString *jsString = @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]. setAttribute('style','-webkit-column-width: 733px; -webkit-column-gap: 20px;');)";
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

}

I've confirmed via alerts that the style attributes are being set correctly, so I don't understand why they are having no effect. Executing that same javascript string via the console in Safari has the desired affect. Any idea why this doesn't work in UIWebView?

Comment: You're setting them after the dom and the page have already loaded. Should the act of setting them automatically cause them to be applied to the already loaded page?

Comment: Yes, I think setting these properties after page load should work. Or, more accurately, I don't know of any reason why it wouldn't work and I have confirmed it does work on Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand why the code above doesn't work, but I was able to find a workaround by grabbing the external stylesheet for file via javascript, then editing that CSS file via javascript.

```
NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";

NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
"ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
"mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
"}";

NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", webView.frame.size.height, webView.frame.size.width];
NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];
//NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')", currentTextSize];


[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];
```

Hat tip to the [AePubReader project](https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader) where I found this code.